# Is possible to use Atomic Design in PHP Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade, atomic-design

In React, you can create separate components in folders, which have their own JS and CSS.
In Laravel I saw the possibility of using `@includes()`, `@extends()`, `@yarn()`, and `@section()` sending parameters to edit the internal content and simulate react, but in relation to dependencies (css and js), these are not allocated in the correct positions on the blade. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions isn't extremely clear, but assuming my understanding of your question, here is one of the possibility.

1. You create the following blade structures:

```
|---- View
       |----- Inc
               |--- header.blade.php
               |--- footer.blade.php
       |--- main.blade.php
```

Now, within your main.blade.php

```
@include('inc.header')

 // all your main content here

@include('inc.footer)
```